# mysql_real_escape_string not letting string through

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to sanitize a string going into my database. But with the code below, I don't get the update to my db.

First page posts this in an input form:

```
$note="Here is some example text";
```

Receiving page:

```
$note = $_POST['note'];
$note = mysql_real_escape_string($note);
$sql="UPDATE some_table SET notes='$note' WHERE id='$some_id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

When I take out the mysql_real_escape_string line it works, but not with it in there.
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql` library as it is deprecated in favor of `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Was there an error when trying to execute the query?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using Prepared Statement, mysql_real_escape_string() won't full protect you from SQL Injection.

Example for your update:

```
<?php
// connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// query
$sql = "UPDATE some_table 
        SET notes=? 
        WHERE id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($$_POST['note'], $some_id));
?>
```

More details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php